# Python - If > 16 and for in dictionary list comprehension

Tags: python

I need to make a function that returns a dictionary where values are doubled if values from previous dictionary are bigger than 10

```
def dbl(d1):
    d = {x: d1.get(x, 0) * 2 for x in set(d1)}
    return d
```

This is my code that doubles. I can't figure out where to put if > 10

My try:

```
a = {"a": 1, "b": 17, "c": 15} 

def dbl(d1):
    d = {x: d1.get(x, 0) * 2 for x in set(d1) if x > 10}
    return d
```

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `{k: v*2 for k, v in a.items() if v>10}`?

Comment: Your problem isn't the location of `if x > 10`. It's that `x` is a string when you don't want it to be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. You have the `if` in the right place (assuming you want to *exclude* the small values from the result, rather than just... not doubling them). The problem is that `x` is not the thing you want to compare to `10`, because `x` is the dict *key* and it is the *value* that needs to be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Any item in `set(d1)` gives you one of dictionary keys ("a", "b", "c"), not dictionary values. Try to put `if d1[x] > 10` instead of `if x > 10`

Answer (score -1):

Using dict comprehension you can do is as follows :

```py
def dbl(d1):
    d = {k:v*2  if v>10 else v for (k,v) in d1.items()}
    return d
```

This solution permits to keep the value that are < 10 and double the ones that are > 10.